# Printing image of GoJs using JavaScript, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, gojs

I need to print a jpeg image that I create from `Go.js` code in **JavaScript**. I am calling the `makeJPEG()` function on click of a button. FYI, `myDiagram.makeImage()` returns a new `HTMLImageElement` with the image data as its source(it is a Go.js code). But I am not able to get the image in my print window or my print.
Here is how it looks:

```
function makeJPEG() {
    var jpegImage = myDiagram.makeImage({
        scale: 1,
        background: "#3d76d3",
        type: "image/jpeg"
    });
    PrintContent(jpegImage);
}

function PrintContent(jpegImage) {
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=200,width=400');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(jpegImage);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the `printWindow.document` as the `document:` option in your call to **Diagram.makeImage**.  This is documented in https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#makeImageData.